# Django Template Tag With No Arguments

Tags: django, templates

I have a template tag that returns a random hex color.  I have tested this out and the code returns the color correctly.  However when I load the templatetag in my template and call it it returns a value of 'None'.
I have read the django documentation on template tags, and stackoverflow questions regarding this topic but can't find an answer for this situation.  I'm sure it is very simple, and feel the problem is coming from a misunderstanding of how arguments are being passed into the function.

Any help, even just a point to some relevant documentation I may be missing would be much appreciated.

```
from django import template
import random


register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def random_color():
    r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
    color_data = '#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r())
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to add

```
return color_data
```

To the end of your function...

Comment: Thanks Ben! I don't know how I missed that, must have been kind of sleep deprived I suppose.